# how to fire onchange event in chosen prototype javascript select box?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, prototype-chosen

I am using chosen prototype for select box. Now i want to fire onchange event on that select box.
here is the link for [chosen prototype](http://julesjanssen.github.com/chosen/)

How to do this. please help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Event.simulate.js"></script>
<script src="/js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/chosen/chosen.proto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div class="side-by-side clearfix" style="margin-bottom:14px;">

        <select data-placeholder="Select Loacation"  class="chzn-select" tabindex="2" name="source">
          <option value="">Select Loacation</option>
          <option value="">option1</option>
          <option value="">option2</option>
        </select>
  </div>



Event.observe($(".chzn-select"),'change', function(){

//alert($(".chzn-select").chosen());

})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the "addEventListener" method on the select box object.

EDIT - here's an example:

```
document.getElementById('selecboxid').addEventListener('change', SomeFunction(), false);
```

Answer (score 12):

In this line you have used [`$()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/) with a class name, which it does not support.

```
Event.observe($(".chzn-select"),'change', function(){
```

A class name can be used multiple times so an array is returned from [`$$()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/), here is one way to work with arrays.

```
$$(".chzn-select").invoke('observe', 'change', function() {
    ...
});
```

---

I haven't used Chosen before; it's instructions say it needs to be setup so you might have to do this outside of the change event.

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    $$(".chzn-select").each(function(select) {
        new Chosen(select);
    });
});
```

Comment: hi, its not working, can you give me an example with alert please,

Comment: Now that I've read a suitable [example](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/master/example.proto.html) I see I was setting it up wrong. Here is [a minimal fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBKeW/) that works, to get it looking like the official one I had to link to [the same CSS](http://julesjanssen.github.com/chosen/css/chosen.css) but of course you can make your own.

Comment: hi everything is working fine, but i have two select boxes on the same page, so how to distinguish those?

Comment: Give them each an `id` attribute.

Comment: hi @clockworkgeek i want to update the second select box based on the first select box, can you give me small example please.