# Add a static link in Magento menu

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I have many subcategories and displaying them all at the same time is not user friendly.
I was thinking of putting only 10 in the navigation and hide all the others.

But is there a way to add a "View All" in the bottom of the dropdown for each category?

Something like:
L1 -> L2 -> 10 L3 Items / "View All"

I would prefer to avoid an extension as I have the design already incorporated.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I just participated in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8455569/471559) that happened to use the [Chosen widget](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) for dropdowns. I'm really impressed with Chosen and it's ease of skinning. It would improve user-friendliness.