# jQuery Chosen not firing onchange event when value is changed through JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

## [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/y6BCP/)

I've set up a `select` with 3 `option`s (1 blank) in the fiddle. When I switch from `foo` to `bar` manually, the `change` listener fires normally.

Now if I reset the `select` through JS with the [code posted in some answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897760/jquery-chosen-reset), the `change` event does not fire for the newly selected blank option, furthermore, if I select the option which was selected before clicking in the `reset` button the `onchange` event won't fire either.

I'm sure the `select`'s value **is** being changed with the function above, which can be seen in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/y6BCP/1/), but the `select`'s `onchange` event simply doesn't fire.

I've also tried `onchange`, `onclick`, `oninput` events to no avail. Right now I'm wondering if I should use a MutationObserver or remove the rendered chosen element from the DOM and create another, but I'm probably overthinking it. Any help is appreciated.

Also:

This answer helped me a lot: [jQuery Chosen reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897760/jquery-chosen-reset)

This answer didn't help: [how to fire onchange event in chosen prototype javascript select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455569/how-to-fire-onchange-event-in-chosen-prototype-javascript-select-box)

Code for future reference if jsfiddle.net is taken down:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <select id="chosen">
        <option value="!!EMPTY VALUE!!"></option>
        <option value="foo">foo</option>
        <option value="bar">bar</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('#chosen').chosen();

    $('#wrapper').on('change', '#chosen', function() {
        console.log('onchange: ' + this.value);
    });

    $('#reset').click(function() {
        $("#chosen").val('').trigger("liszt:updated"); //doesn't work
        //$("#chosen").prop('selectedIndex', 0).trigger("liszt:updated"); //doesn't work either
        console.log('reset: ' + $('option:selected').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: **ASP.Net Webforms**: I came across this question when my app seemed to have this problem but it turned out to be a Javascript error caused by ASP WebForm Validators. See this [jQuery-UI ticket](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4071#comment:9)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to trigger the change after you change the value with `$(selector).trigger("change")`

```
$('#reset').click(function() {
        $("#chosen").val('').trigger("change"); //doesn't work
        //$("#chosen").prop('selectedIndex', 0).trigger("liszt:updated");
        console.log('reset: ' + $('option:selected').val());
    });
```

Comment: There's still the `foo` -> `reset` -> `foo` which won't trigger the last `foo`, but I should be able to figure that on my own now.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté what is the function `.chosen`?

Comment: `.chosen` is the Chosen plugin itself which transform the select into a `chosen` select, dw it's probably a bug in their code as usual. =]

Comment: I've solved it, a little ugly solution but yeah, for future people who may come across the same issue: `$('#chosen_chzn').remove(); $('#chosen').val('').change().removeClass('chzn-done').chosen();` [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/y6BCP/2/).

Comment: `#chosen` is the ID of the `select` in the code above, so a more appropriate solution: `var selId = 'chosen'; $('#'+selId+'_chzn').remove(); $('#'+selId).val('').change().removeClass('chzn-done').chosen();` - [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/y6BCP/3/) - and a final note, Chosen is the worst plugin in terms of adding new functionality I've ever seen.

Answer (score 5):

Copying an answer out of the comments by Fabrício Matté that worked for me so others don't see this post and miss a solution at first like I did.

```
$('#chosen_chzn').remove();
$('#chosen').val('').change().removeClass('chzn-done').chosen();
```

[See this on his Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/y6BCP/2/)

I originally tried to continue using the `.trigger('liszt:updated')` call instead of the `.change()` but that did not work. Didn't see the reasoning behind `.removeClass('chzn-done')` either but this is also essential or your select box will vanish.

Comment: Actually, I think I've found yet another "better" solution. Not too sure. I think I just upgraded to [Select 2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) which fires the `change` event with just calling `.change()` on the original input.

Comment: +1 though for those who are stuck with Chosen, I don't fully remember the reasoning behind removing the `chzn-done` class but I'm quite sure it was because `chzn-done` applies `display:none` to `select` elements which you've called `.chosen()` on, and calling the `.chosen()` on elements with that class wouldn't work.

Comment: I believe if you don't remove chzn-done then calling chosen() does nothing - it believes it has already set itself up. Sort of a poor mans guard.